# How do I branch if message.properties-code exists

Tags: grails, groovy, internationalization

I want to branch if a message-property-code does exist or not.

```
<g:if test="${message(code: 'default.code.foo')}">
  true
</g:if><g:else>
 false
</g:else>
```

should answer `true` if there a message property named `default.code.foo` and `false` if not.

It fails because it answers the code if there is no property for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you supply a default that's a blank string?

```
<g:if test="${message(code: 'default.code.foo', default:'')}">
  true
</g:if><g:else>
 false
</g:else>
```

This will equate to false under [Groovy's truth](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth)

Comment: I believe you could also do something like 

    "${g.message(code: 'specific.code.foo', default: ''} ?: g.message(code: 'default.code.foo'}"

as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Then why don't you just test if the String returned is the code itself?

```
<g:if test="${message(code: 'default.code.foo') == 'default.code.foo'}">
  true
</g:if><g:else>
 false
</g:else>
```

If you need to do this in several places and want to make the code a bit more concise, then put this logic in a tag lib.

```
class MsgTagLib {
    static namespace = 'msg'

    def messageSource

    private static final NO_ARGS = [].toArray();

    def exists = {attrs ->

        try {
            messageSource.getMessage(attrs.code, NO_ARGS, Locale.default) 
            out << true
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            out << false                
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call this in a GSP using:

```
<msg:exists code="default.code.foo"/>
```

**Note**

1. The tag lib above is 100% untested, beware!
2. The `exists` tag in it's form above doesn't support parameterized messages

Comment: sometimes it is far to easy to see the solution... :) sure that solves it!